# Imagekit SpecFields to Scale down images, but not scale up

Tags: django, imagekit

Imagekit will scale down uploaded images larger than 800x500, however it will also scale up images smaller than 800x500.

How can a ImageSpecField be created so that images which fit well within the defined size are not scaled up?

```
post_embed_image = ImageSpecField([SmartCrop(800, 500)], image_field='original_image')
post_embed_resized_image = ImageSpecField([SmartResize(800, 500)], image_field='original_image')
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turns how the [imagekit docs](http://django-imagekit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) are outdated and have no mention of the ResizeToFit processor with the Upscale boolean

https://github.com/jdriscoll/django-imagekit/blob/master/imagekit/processors/resize.py

The following ImageSpecField will resize large images and preserve smaller images.

```
post_resized_image = ImageSpecField([ResizeToFit(800, 500, False)], image_field='original_image')
```